# How to make height of blocks equal in line

Tags: javascript, html

I have such html, and want to make blocks ".equal-height" same height in different lines.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 equal-height">Some different by height content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 equal-height">Some different by height content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 equal-height">Some different by height content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 equal-height">Some different by height content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 equal-height">Some different by height content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 equal-height">Some different by height content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 equal-height">Some different by height content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 equal-height">Some different by height content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 equal-height">Some different by height content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 equal-height">Some different by height content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 equal-height">Some different by height content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 equal-height">Some different by height content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I has script, but result is like this

```
var EqualBlocks = document.querySelectorAll(".equal-height");
var equalBlocksLength = EqualBlocks.length;
var maxHeight = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < equalBlocksLength; i++){
  var height = EqualBlocks[i].offsetHeight;
  if(maxHeight < height) maxHeight = height;
  var top = 0;
  var elem = EqualBlocks[i];
  while(elem){
    top += elem.offsetTop;
    elem = elem.offsetParent;
}
```

[image: wrong equal blocks]

When i need equal blocks only in one line, like this.

[image: equal blocks]

Any ideas or some sources with information?

> And, i need pure js, but no jquery!

Comment: I'd suggest using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: what's your CSS? The code in your question doesn't generate colored squares.